# Is it possible to use Observables in a way where I can constant feedback?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Say I have a subscription to an observable here

```
this.calculateService.CalculateBestRoute().subscribe(
  data => {
    drawRoute(data);
  }
);
```

And say the CalculateBestRoute function takes a long time to do because there is a number of things it does but while it's doing these things, the route gets better and better.

```
public CalculateBestRoute(): Observable<Route> {
    let bestRoute;
    DoThing1(bestRoute);
    DoThing2(bestRoute);
    DoThing3(bestRoute);
    DoThing4(bestRoute);
    return Observable.of(bestRoute);
}
```

If I had this code, the bestRoute would only be returned at the very end. But what if I didn't want to wait - what if I just wanted to see whatever the bestRoute is at time?

Is it possible to using Observables? I'm looking for something like below...

```
public CalculateBestRoute(observable : Observable<Route>) {
    let bestRoute;
    DoThing1(bestRoute);
    observable.update(bestRoute);
    DoThing2(bestRoute);
    observable.update(bestRoute);
    DoThing3(bestRoute);
    observable.update(bestRoute);
    DoThing4(bestRoute);
    observable.update(bestRoute);
}
```

Comment: I think you need to look at the docs for [`Observable.create()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-create). You should see that `.next()` in there is the basic method for "pumping new things" into an observable stream. Your question could be less obtuse, but this seems what you are generally trying to say.

Comment: Your example isn't very coherent, but it sounds like you're describing a [subject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.md). I wrote a blog post on how we're using this pattern, if you want more info: http://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe - thanks yeah maybe what I'm after isn't even an observable. I'll take a look

Comment: A Subject **is** an Observable. But if your computation is synchronous anyway, Modifying the state of some component, AFAIK, won't have any effect until the next change detection, which will not happen until the computation is complete. This looks like a job for a worker.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're describing a [subject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.md). This is both an observer and an observable, so you can subscribe to it and also push new data into it.

```ts
private routeSubject = new Subject<any>();
public route$ = this.routeSubject.asObservable();

public calculateBestRoute(): void {
  let bestRoute: any;
  DoThing1(bestRoute);
  this.routeSubject.next(bestRoute);
  DoThing2(bestRoute);
  this.routeSubject.next(bestRoute);
  DoThing3(bestRoute);
  this.routeSubject.next(bestRoute);
  DoThing4(bestRoute);
  this.routeSubject.next(bestRoute);
}
```

Note that the subject itself is private, then exposed publicly via a read-only observable. The method is now just a trigger to go through the process of calculating the route, so a consumer would look like:

```ts
this.service.route$.subscribe(bestRoute => {
  ...
}); 
this.service.calculateBestRoute();
```

I've written an article on my blog about how we're using this pattern for HTTP services that may provide some background: http://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html.

Answer (score 0):

Publish/subscribe pattern can be implemented using `Subject`.

The following code is the working demonstration.

```
interface Route {
    length: number;
}

let routeSubject = new Subject<Route>();

function update(route:Route) {
    routeSubject.next(route);
}

function doThing(route:Route) {
    route.length++;
}

function calculateBestRoute(observable: Observable<Route>) {
    let bestRoute:Route = { length: 0};

    doThing(bestRoute);
    update(bestRoute);
    doThing(bestRoute);
    update(bestRoute);
    doThing(bestRoute);
    update(bestRoute);
    doThing(bestRoute);
    update(bestRoute);
}

routeSubject.subscribe(value => console.log(`updated: ${value.length}`));
calculateBestRoute(routeSubject);
```

**Result:**

```
updated: 1
updated: 2
updated: 3
updated: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

`calculateBestRoute` must create and return an observable of best routes:

```
public calculateBestRoute() {
  return Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {
    let bestRoute;
    DoThing1(bestRoute);
    observer.onNext(bestRoute);
    DoThing2(bestRoute);
    observer.onNext(bestRoute);
    DoThing3(bestRoute);
    observer.onNext(bestRoute);
    DoThing4(bestRoute);
    observer.onNext(bestRoute);
    observer.onCompleted();
  })
}
```